# pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: ('Could not convert X with type Y: did not recognize Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type')

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow, fastparquet

Using `pyarrow` to convert a `pandas.DataFrame` containing `Player` objects to a `pyarrow.Table` with the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<{self.name} ({self.age})>'

data = [
    Player('Jack', 21, 'm'),
    Player('Ryan', 18, 'm'),
    Player('Jane', 35, 'f'),
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['player'])
print(pa.Table.from_pandas(df))
```

we get the error:

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: ('Could not convert <Jack (21)> with type Player: did not recognize Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type', 'Conversion failed for column 0 with type object')
```

Same error encountered by using

```
df.to_parquet('players.pq')
```

Is it possible for `pyarrow` to fallback to serializing these Python objects using `pickle`? Or is there a better solution? The `pyarrow.Table` will eventually be written to disk using `Parquet.write_table()`.

- *Using Python 3.8.0, pandas 0.25.3, pyarrow 0.13.0.*
- *`pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet()` does not support multi index, so a solution using `pq.write_table(pa.Table.from_dataframe(pandas.DataFrame))` is preferred.*

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please open a JIRA issue with Apache Arrow? We don't really engage with users or developers on StackOverflow. https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion will be to insert the data into the DataFrame already serialized.

## Best option - Use dataclass (python >=3.7)

Define the Player class as a dataclass by the decorator, and let the serialization be done natively for you (to JSON).

```
import pandas as pd
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class PlayerV2:
    name:str
    age:int
    gender:str

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<{self.name} ({self.age})>'


dataV2 = [
    PlayerV2(name='Jack', age=21, gender='m'),
    PlayerV2(name='Ryan', age=18, gender='m'),
    PlayerV2(name='Jane', age=35, gender='f'),
]

# The serialization is done natively to JSON
df_v2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['player'])
print(df_v2)

# Can still get the objects's attributes by deserializeing the record
json.loads(df_v2["player"][0])['name']
```

## Manually serialize the object (python < 3.7)

Define a serialization function in the Player class and serialize each of the instances before the creation of the Dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<{self.name} ({self.age})>'
    
    # The serialization function for JSON, if for some reason you really need pickle you can use it instead
    def toJSON(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)

# Serialize the objects before inserting it into the DataFrame
data = [
    Player('Jack', 21, 'm').toJSON(),
    Player('Ryan', 18, 'm').toJSON(),
    Player('Jane', 35, 'f').toJSON(),
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['player'])

# You can see all the data inserted as a serialized json into the column player
print(df)

# Can still get the objects's attributes by deserializeing the record
json.loads(df["player"][0])['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding there is problem with 'type' because of **repr**
Try this approach(it works):

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender

    def other(self):
        return f'<{self.name} ({self.age})>'

data = [
    Player('Jack', 21, 'm').other(),
    Player('Ryan', 18, 'm').other(),
    Player('Jane', 35, 'f').other(),
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['player'])
print(df)
        player
0  <Jack (21)>
1  <Ryan (18)>
2  <Jane (35)>

print(pa.Table.from_pandas(df))

pyarrow.Table
player: string
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is parquet support format <string (int)>.
But it works on dict, list.

for a python class.
by calling object.**dict** to get a dictionary representation of an object.

for example
the following works

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa

@dataclass
class Player:
  name: str
  age: int
  gender: str

players = [
  {"name": "player1", "age": 12, "gender": "f"},
  {"name": "player2", "age": 22, "gender": "m"},
  {"name": "player3", "age": 18, "gender": "m"}
]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["players"] = [Player(**r).__dict__ for r in players]

pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to [extend pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html#extension-types) with your own custom Dtype. Pandas gives a fair bit of documentation on how to [create an extension Dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionDtype.html#pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionDtype), and you can look at the [base class](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/dtypes/base.py) for more details, and [existing extensions](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/dtypes/dtypes.py) for examples.

That said, it's a bit involved, and if all you are looking to do is work around the "could not convert" error and get your data printed or saved to parquet, I'd recommend some form of pre-serializing as mentioned in other answers, or implement `__str__` on your class, then convert the column type to `str`. While you're at it, since you'll be using `__str__` for its intended purpose, you can improve your `__repr__` to return a string that looks [like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__). Putting it all together, it'll be something like:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Player("{self.name}", {self.age}, "{self.gender}")'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'<{self.name} ({self.age})>'


data = [
    Player('Jack', 21, 'm'),
    Player('Ryan', 18, 'm'),
    Player('Jane', 35, 'f'),
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['player'])
for col in [c for c in df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns]:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('str')

print(pa.Table.from_pandas(df))
df.to_parquet('players.pq')
print([repr(d) for d in data])
```

This gives the output:

```
pyarrow.Table
player: string
----
player: [["<Jack (21)>","<Ryan (18)>","<Jane (35)>"]]
# No output from to_parquet b/c there was no error
['Player("Jack", 21, "m")', 'Player("Ryan", 18, "m")', 'Player("Jane", 35, "f")']
```

Naturally, if you want to keep the original `DataFrame` around with the original types, you'll want to change those column types on a copy instead of the original.